# How to extract the coefficient from an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

Here is the expression. 
[image: the expression]

I want to extract the coefficient just as the table showing below.
[image: the coefficient]

I can do it by hand, but I expect a code that can automatically identify how many  differenct terms there are ,what is its coefficient and show them all in a table.

this is the expression for Mma.

> expr= (3 Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a])/8+1/8 E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]+1/8 E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]+3/8 E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]-(3 Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b])/8+1/8 E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]-1/8 E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]+3/8 E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]-(Sqrt[3] Subscript[3, a])/8-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+(Sqrt[3] Subscript[3, b])/8-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]

---

I think of a example as below:

```
tab[expr_] := {#, 
     Coefficient[
      expr, #]} & /@ (expr // 
       List @@ # & // # /. {Power[_, _] -> 1, Rational[_, _] -> 1, 
         E -> 1} & // Union) // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

so, `expr//tab` will get the table above.

Comment: Use `Coefficient`.

Comment: It works. But how do I get the terms first?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "I expect a code that can automatically identify how many differenct terms there are ". It is the fist column of the talbe.

Comment: Does that make any sense? Do you want the terms of 3/8? Of Sqrt[3]/8? Of Exp[2 Pi]?

Comment: sorry for my poor English; you can see the supplement of Question. What I really want is like the function `tab`.

Comment: not sure how your expressions look like, not sure what you dislike about your `tab`, here's another approach, maybe it helps? Voilà: `Grid[Transpose@{#, Coefficient[expr, #]} &@Union[Cases[expr, Times[c___ : 1, a : _Subscript, b :___Subscript] :> a b, 2]],Frame -> All]`

Comment: I like this, thank you Dirk.

Answer (score 5):

Let that you have the variables

```
vars= {Subscript[1, a],Subscript[1, b],Subscript[2, a],Subscript[2, b],Subscript[3, a],
       Subscript[3, b]}
```

and

```
expr=(3 Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a])/8+1/8 E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]+1/8 E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]+3/8 E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, b] Subscript[2, a]-(3 Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b])/8+1/8 E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]-1/8 E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]+3/8 E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[1, a] Subscript[2, b]-(Sqrt[3] Subscript[3, a])/8-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, a]+(Sqrt[3] Subscript[3, b])/8-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]-1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(2 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]+1/8 Sqrt[3] E^(3 I [Theta]) Subscript[3, b]
```

to get the first column use the command

```
v = List@@Expand[Collect[expr, vars, 1 &]]
```

now things are easy:

```
({#,Coefficient[expr,#]}&/@v)// Grid[#, Frame -> All]&
```

You can tweak the `Grid` to your liking

Comment: it help me a lot. Thank you 1701D.

Comment: @cmc to create the list `vars` you can use `Cases` if it is too long to do by hand.